# Hyperparameters chosen by CV on train dataset don't perform well on validation/test dataset

Tags: cross-validation, hyperparameter, tuning

I've used the following objective function to assess best hyper-parameters using Hyperopt():

```
# Base optimizer with input hyperparameters on Tree based encoding and Logistic Regression 
def mxLogRegGiniComb(cb_depth = 1, max_depth=5, min_rr_delta=0.002, min_samples_MP=50, 
                     min_samples_leaf=0.03, check_rr_leaves=True, check_monotony=False, C=1,
                     corr_threshold=0.9, **kwargs):
    
    from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
    from sklearn import metrics
    from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
    
    # Tree based variable encoding
    vars_comb = tl.cxVarCombs(cb_depth, max_depth, min_rr_delta, min_samples_MP, 
                 min_samples_leaf, check_rr_leaves, check_monotony)
    vars_comb.fit(X_train, y_train, time_train)

    # WOE encoded tree into numeric variable
    X_train_enc_woe = pd.DataFrame(index=X_train.index)
    for key, clf in vars_comb.dic_clf.items():
        if clf.dic_leaves is not None:
            X_train_enc_woe[str(key)+'_tree_enc'] = clf.encoding_class(X_train, 'woe')
    
    # Remove duplicated columns
    X_train_enc_nodup_woe = X_train_enc_woe.T.drop_duplicates().T
    
    # Remove very highly correlated variables
    high_cor_woe = mxHighCorr(X_train_enc_nodup_woe, corr_threshold)
    to_drop = []
    for i in range(len(high_cor_woe)):
        if (i == 0) & (high_cor_woe.loc[i, 'corr'] > corr_threshold):
            to_drop.append(high_cor_woe.loc[i, 'var1'])
        #if variables that causes the high correlation has not already been deleted
        elif (high_cor_woe.loc[i, 'var2'] not in to_drop) & (high_cor_woe.loc[i, 'corr'] > corr_threshold):
            to_drop.append(high_cor_woe.loc[i, 'var1'])

    to_drop = list(set(to_drop))  
    to_keep = X_train_enc_nodup_woe[X_train_enc_nodup_woe.columns.difference(to_drop)].columns.to_list()

    # Logistic Regression model with LASSO feature selection
    log_reg = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear', C=C, fit_intercept=False)
    try:
        log_reg.fit(X=X_train_enc_nodup_woe[to_keep], y=(1-y_train['MP']).ravel())
    except Exception:
        pass
    
    # CV Evaluation of performance with constraint of coefficients consistency
    score = 0
    try:
        if all(log_reg.coef_[0] > 0):
            clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', solver='liblinear', C=C, fit_intercept=False)
            roc_auc = cross_val_score(clf, X_train_enc_woe, (1-y_train['MP']).ravel(), 
                                      scoring='roc_auc', cv=10).mean()
            score = 2*roc_auc-1       
    except Exception:
        pass
    # Send the current training score
    return score, vars_comb, log_reg, to_keep, X_train_enc_nodup_woe

# Final optimizer
def mxOptimizer(params):
    score, vars_comb, log_reg, to_keep, X_train_enc_nodup_woe = mxLogRegGiniComb(**params)
    tune.report(mean_gini=score)
```

The search space is as follows:

```
# Establish hyper-parameter search space
import ray.tune as tune
search_space = {
    "cb_depth": tune.choice([2]),
    "check_monotony": tune.choice([False]),
    "min_rr_delta": tune.quniform(0.001, 0.02, 0.0005),
    "C": tune.quniform(0.0001, 0.01, 0.00005),
    "corr_threshold": tune.quniform(0.5, 1, 0.05),
}
```

And the execution is done by the following function:

```
search_alg = HyperOptSearch()
analysis = tune.run(
    mxOptimizer,
    mode="max",
    metric="mean_gini",
    num_samples=50,
    search_alg=search_alg,
    scheduler=ASHAScheduler(),
    config=search_space, 
    progress_reporter=tune.JupyterNotebookReporter(overwrite=True)
)
```

The idea is to assure global model with all Logistic Regression coefficients being positive and maximizing global Gini.

As a result I have a Gini of 0.55 with the following hyper-parameters:

```
Current best trial: 4435e374 with mean_gini=0.552077644083361 and parameters={'cb_depth': 2, 'check_monotony': False, 'min_rr_delta': 0.0125, 'C': 0.00475, 'corr_threshold': 0.5}
```

Though, when using the hyper-parameters to construct a model on global train data and evaluate on outside validation and test data I have very poor results of 0.47 and 0.48 Gini respectively. I suppose that there must be over-fitting. Any idea on how I can have similar results on train and validation/test will be very appreciated.

Comment: Your Gini coefficient drops from 0.55 on the training data to 0.47 and 0.48 on the validation and test set? That seems like a reasonable drop to me. The predictive error will always be optimistic on the training set.

Comment: It may, still I'm pretty sure there is a way to have a better general model. Also, maybe there is a flaw in my approach. On the other hand, I'm not sure if applying directly to train dataset the hyper-parameters evaluated through cross-validation on the same  train dataset is way to go.